# Complicated lookup/query, there has to be an easier way

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have come across this need several times, and can only conclude that there has to be an easier, more scalable way to do what I am trying to do here.

Basically, I need a 3 dimensional table that I can make totals against...

Given two tables:

`| People | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six |
|--------|-----|-----|-------|------|------|-----|
| John   | x   | x   |       |      |      |     |
| James  |     | x   | x     |      |      |     |
| Jim    |     |     | x     | x    |      |     |
| Jean   |     |     |       | x    | x    |     |
| Jammie |     |     |       |      | x    | x   |
| Janis  | x   |     |       |      |      | x   |`

and

`| Event | Data |
|-------|------|
| One   | 1    |
| Two   | 2    |
| Three | 3    |
| Four  | 4    |
| Five  | 5    |
| Six   | 6    |`

I am generating totals, based on non-blank cells in the 1st table, and the corresponding values in the second table to produce:

`| Totals |
|--------|
| 3      |
| 5      |
| 7      |
| 9      |
| 11     |
| 7      |`

I am using a complicated vlookup to produce this:

`=SUM(
  IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[@One])),VLOOKUP(Table1[[#Headers],[One]],Table2,2,FALSE),0),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[@Two])),VLOOKUP(Table1[[#Headers],[Two]],Table2,2,FALSE),0),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[@Three])),VLOOKUP(Table1[[#Headers],[Three]],Table2,2,FALSE),0),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[@Four])),VLOOKUP(Table1[[#Headers],[Four]],Table2,2,FALSE),0),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[@Five])),VLOOKUP(Table1[[#Headers],[Five]],Table2,2,FALSE),0),
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Table1[@Six])),VLOOKUP(Table1[[#Headers],[Six]],Table2,2,FALSE),0)
)`

Obviously this is not scalable, and it leaves a lot of room for human error.  In practice, the real applications involve adding or removing users, and "events".
I feel like I have come across this enough times that I can't be alone and that I must be doing this the hard way.  Is there an easier option?

*Note that in this example I am using a sum, but in some cases, I might have text that I want to do `TEXTJOIN` on or something similar.

Comment: If you feel it’s too complicated in Excel, you probably want a database. Of course, you would have to unpivot that first table.

Comment: You indeed want a database. This would be simple for a SQL query.

Comment: Yeah, at one point I was trying to see if there was a way to use the excel sheet as a data source so that I could use the built-in SQL functionality of excel's external data collectors...

Comment: You can do this pretty easily with SUMPRODUCT(). You need to create two arrays, multiply them and take the SUMPRODUCT. I'm on an iPad right now, but I'll post an answer tomorrow. If you want to try it, the first array would be NOT(ISBLANK($B2:$G2). The second is TRANSPOSE($B$10:$B$16). I'm unpivoting here, for clarity. Try SUMPRODUCT(Array1*Array2) and see if that gives the right answers when filled down.  And I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: You mean to say that in Table 1 you want to count how many X populated in a Column  and adding the value with corresponding value in Table 2.  Like in Table1 2X in 1st col + 1 from data column in Table 2 = 3 ,am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This array formula, filled down from H2 in the screenshot below, gives the results shown.

`=SUM(NOT(ISBLANK($B2:$G2))*TRANSPOSE(B$10:B$15))`

Since this is an array formula, it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

**How it works:** `NOT(ISBLANK($B2:$G2))` gives an array of `True/False` values with `False` wherever a cell in that range is *empty* (see Note below).  If you highlight that part of the formula in the formula bar and hit the <kbd>F9</kbd> key, you'll see the array `{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`. (Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Z to undo that).

`(B$10:B$15)` is just a list of the numbers in your Data column, and `TRANSPOSE()` converts it from a vertical array to a horizontal one.

In the multiplication, `True/False` values are treated as `1` and `0`, so the result is an array with the Data value wherever there was an `x`, and zero elsewhere. Then `SUM()` just adds up the array, and returns the totals as it is filled down.

**Edit:**
OP added to his question, saying that he might have text values in `B6:B10` and operate on them, not with `SUM()`, but another function, possibly `TEXTJOIN()`.

To handle the possibility of non-numeric values, this expression:

`IF(NOT(ISBLANK($B2:$G2)),TRANSPOSE(B$10:B$15),)`

returns an array with the Data value wherever there was an "x", and `False` elsewhere.  It works correctly for both text and numeric values.

By including the `value_if_false` in the `IF()` (after the last comma), the `False` values could be replaced with `0` or `blank` or whatever might be required by the function acting on the array.

**Notes:**

1. `ISBLANK()` should really be named `ISEMPTY()`, because a cell has
   to truly be empty for `ISBLANK()` to return `True`.  If the cell
   contains a formula, but appears blank, `ISBLANK()` will return
   `False`. `ISTEXT()` has the same problem, so if you do have formulas
   in the "blank" cells, you can change the first array to
   `(($B2:$G2)="x")`
2. If `TRANSPOSE()` wasn't present, the multiplication (and the `IF()`
   function) would give a 2D array, which would get messy.

I hope this helps and best of luck.

Comment: I feel like this might be close, but since you can't "multiply" test, how might that work in a text function instead of an arithmetic one.  e.g. if table 2's data was the names of fruits~ and I might expect to see in Totals: apple, banana | banana, cherry | cherry, durian... etc.

Comment: I just used multiplication because you initially had numbers to sum.  This formula creates the same array and works with text or numbers: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($B2:$G2)),TRANSPOSE(B$10:B$15))`.  If you replace the integers in `B10:B15` with Uno,Dos,Tres etc, this formula returns the array  `{"Uno","Dos",FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`.

Comment: Depending on what function this array will be used in, the IF() can replace the False elements with 0, or blank, or ...

Comment: Ah-ha!  I'd say that is the real answer right there!

Comment: There you go. Help yourself.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a little more, there is a much simpler solution using `SUMIF()`.  But your second table has to be arranged horizontally.

`=SUMIF(B2:G2,"x",B$10:G$10)`

[image]

Comment: SUMIF totally works, but only for arithmetic sums, however I may want to do things with TEXTJOIN, or other non-sum functions.

Comment: The most general solution is the other answer, and the key is forming the array.  That array can be fed to any function that accepts arrays as a parameter.  If you found one of these answers helpful, kindly click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: Respectfully, helpful, versus and answer to the complete question are two different things.  The question is not completely answered until we have solved the text part of the question~

Comment: See the modified formula in the comment to my other answer.